# Linux socket: Too many open files

Tags: linux, sockets, socket.io

I am getting socket error: `Too many open files` for some time later. When I check `lsof` for my process, fd count has reached 1023(Max limit). I am trying to find out which socket did not close properly in my process. After code walk through, in my module all socket closing properly. But my process using some lib. I don't know whether the problematic sockets are opened by any lib.

How to find out which socket is opened by which module?

I am expecting how to fix this issue without increase max count.

Comment: You could try valgrind with `--track-fds=yes` to get a report of the non-closed file descriptors, and their backtrace.

Comment: Hi @skandigraun,
Thank you. This method was helpful to find my issue. I used below command to run valgrind.

cmd : **valgrind -q --track-fds=yes ./xxx.bin**

Comment: @Oandriy I don't see any evidence to connect this question with [tag:embedded-linux].

Comment: Then its fine ignore it.